# Can anyone tell the difference between SOAP and REST?

Tags: rest, soap

I have the web service URL, login and password, but I can't understand is this SOAP or REST service.

I understand that SOAP is a protocol and REST is just an architecture, but I can't understand the difference between their mechanisms.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you really not [Google](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?hl=en&btnG=Google+Search#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=6&gs_id=m&xhr=t&q=soap+vs+rest&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=soap+v&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=38d0ddbb4033f53a&biw=1876&bih=963) this before posting here? What's wrong with the plethora of answers available there? Did you have a specific question that you couldn't find an answer to? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: SOAP is a protocol, while REST is an approach. Take a look at this link to answer your own question: http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest

Comment: I asked for "normal", humanity description. I read many posts and infos about this theme but don't actually understood the difference between their realisations.

Comment: @ChristianVarga: the more I read about this question on Google, the more I want to ask exactly this question. It's kind of like going up to Socrates and saying, "Hey! Everyone knows what justice is, so stop asking about it."

Comment: @micahhoover The same questions lead to the same answers. If you ask a question and the answers don't make sense, asking the same question again isn't going to result in a different answer. And this question has been answered _many_ times before. If you don't understand it, explain _which part_ you don't understand. Use examples, demos, and scenarios to help _us_ understand what _you_ don't understand. That's how a good question is put together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOAP is a set of [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/) for web services protocols.  In simple terms, those protocols define an XML "wrapper" for providing and consuming web services.

REST is a different kind of concept (as you noted); [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) defines it as an "architecture for distributed systems"; to web developers it's a convenient way of configuring URI schemes to retrieve and update resources.  HTTP GET to *server/customers/1* gets you info about customer 1, and HTTP PUT to the same URI updates that customer.

In colloquial terms REST is sort of a lightweight alternative to SOAP.  Maybe you don't need all the headers, security, and schema that SOAP provides; or maybe you're working in a bandwidth-sensitive area (like mobile web), where you don't want all that overhead.  REST is kind of the shorthand way of referring to that alternate paradigm, and tends to get lumped together with other techniques like JSON and AJAX, even though they aren't technically related.

Answer (score 1):

```
SOAP VS REST

SOAP is a protocol.
REST is an architectural style.

SOAP stands for Simple Object Access Protocol.  
REST stands for REpresentational State Transfer.

SOAP can't use REST because it is a protocol.   
REST can use SOAP web services because it is a concept and can use any protocol like HTTP, SOAP.

SOAP uses services interfaces to expose the business logic. 
REST uses URI to expose business logic.

SOAP defines standards to be strictly followed. 
REST does not define too much standards like SOAP.

SOAP defines its own security.  
RESTful web services inherits security measures from the underlying transport.

SOAP permits XML data format only.  
REST permits different data format such as Plain text, HTML, XML, JSON etc.
```

Comment: Please prove a statement like that SOAP requires more bandwith than REST. This is a rumor based on SOAP exchanging mainly XML messages with an envelope. A REST response, i.e. also in XML, should contain plenty of links clients can use to drive their application state further. This bloats up the actual message size. Also, a statement like SOAP is less preferred than REST is kind of an opinionated view. There are still plenty of SOAP services out there and most of these so called REST APIs are RPC anyway and thus should not count towards your REST count to start with